# How do I take a User inputted msg, and decrypt or encrypt the msg using 2 Lists

Tags: python, list, encryption

How to make two functions. One to Encrypt and one to Decrypt the message and implement it in the already using code.

Sample of **encryption**: `'My test text is here'.upper()` Output: `UJ 8ZV8 8Z08 AV DZOZ`

**Decrypt** sample: `'V845X6QZO3Y6L AV 4LZV6UZ'` Output: `'STACKOVERFLOW IS AWESOME'`

```
List1 = ("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",".",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
List2 = (4,"R",5,"G","Z",3,2,"D","A","E","X","Y","U","I",6,"W",7,"O","V",8,"F","Q","L",0,"J",".","H",9,"C","B","N","S","P","M",1,"T","K")

while choice != EXIT:
    display_menu()

    choice = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 3."))

    if choice == encrypt:
        encrypt_msg = str(input("Give me a Message to Encrypt Please"))
    elif choice == decrypt:
        result = 0
        decrypt_msg = str(input("Give me Your message to decrypt please."))

        print("Exiting...")
    else:
        Print("Error...Invalid Response")
```

That is the two List above, I am New to Programming and still grasping the basics, The program needs to take the message from user and using the two lists provided decrypt and encrypt the message and display it, I have tried searching for similar questions but the soloutions are commands and methods we have not learned in class, Id appreciate any help and explanation on how to program the situation above.

Comment: Suppose I gave you one letter to encrypt: `"C"` (1) What is the correct output? (2) Explain in precise terms why that's the correct output (3) Do you have any ideas how to translate any of that into code? Which parts are you stuck on?

Comment: Encrypting the Letter C should turn it into the number 5, I am New to programming so please bare with me, I am confused on how to take the users Message encrypt it and 0r decrypt it, Say the user entered Hello the output should be DZYY6, and if the user enters DZYY6 to decrypt the out put should be HELLO

Comment: I understand all of that, and I will bear with you. So answer question (2): how do you know that C should be translated to 5? I know it may sound like a stupid question, but putting it in precise terms will help you solve the problem. Why *exactly* does C become 5? Why doesn't C become Q?

Comment: I believe it is to be the correct output because C is number 3 in the List, as in the third item to be in the list, and 5 is number 3 in the Second list, as in the third item to be in the list. I believe the solution is a For loop but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Right, so the first question is how to write code which finds that C is the third item in the first list. Yes, a for loop is one way to do that. Do you have any idea how to get started on such a loop? It's OK if your first attempt is wrong. You can also google this specific question, instead of the broader encryption/decryption question. If you try googling it and don't find anything, tell me what keywords you searched for.

Comment: I know you can use the Index command to find the position of a value in a list, so id imagine you would incorporate it into the for loop to retrieve the position of C, I have searched "Python Finding index value in a List" Tried adding the Keywords for loop to that as well. Iv also realize that C is actually  in the list since the first value starts at 0 and not 1. So forgive my Inexperience but I'm not entirely sure how to get started on such a loop. Thank you as well for being patient with me and helping me.

Comment: Yes, you can use the `index` method. In that case you do not need a loop, at least not for the problem of finding the position of C. So, can you write a snippet of code that includes `"C"`, `index`, and `List1` and outputs `2`? It's just one expression, no loops or anything else required.

Comment: I understand that, would there be a way to apply that for more then just C tho, lets say "tackoverflow is awesome" there would have to be a better way to output the list2 results then individual snippets of code using the index command. Though I am understanding where you are getting at.

Comment: We're working towards it. Eventually there will be a loop that goes over all the letters in the input. But you haven't shown me that you're ready for that step yet, and we have to solve one subproblem at a time. To go a bit further, can you define a function `translate_character(char, in_list, out_list)` such that `translate_letter("C", List1, List2)` is `"5"`, and `translate_letter("5", List2, List1)` is `"C"`?

Comment: Thats where I am confused, how would I make a function pulling out C from list one, and seeing that it is the same as 5 In list two, would I ask it to pull out the second index In list two? Seeing how C is the second Index? Sorry for leaving I had to take a break from the question and head to work.

Comment: OK I might have moved too fast. First answer the question in my previous comment - write that snippet of code using `index`.

Comment: List1.index(“C”) and the output should be 2 correct?

Comment: You should never be asking me what the output of code is, you should be running it to see. Yes, that's correct. Now, what snippet of code involving `2` (or equivalently, `List1.index(“C”)`) and `List2` produces `5`? Combining the concepts in these two snippets, you should be able to write the function `translate_letter`. Again, no loops are needed.

Comment: I though I was onto the solution, having the variable "letter = list1.index("C") then making the variable "letter = list2____(letter)" but I'm not sure how I would do that, I am not sure if I am on the right track, and would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Firstly, don't name two different concepts with the same name. Call the first variable `i`, `index`, or `position`. For the second part, you are sort of on the right track, but what you want isn't a method like `index`. There's no word, `.`, or `()` - getting an item from a list has a different syntax. It'll be one of the first things mentioned in most tutorials about lists, or you can google it directly.

Comment: list1 = ["A","B","C"]
list2 = ["D","E",5]
I = list1.index("C")
L = list2[I]
print (L)    I tried this small code and got an output of 5!

Comment: Great! Keep your variable names lowercase, but also don't name anything `l`. Now define that `translate_letter` function to work for any values. Then you will need a for loop over the characters in a string, collect the translated versions, and combine them into one output string. This is a common operation, so if you go through exercises and tutorials until you're comfortable with strings, lists, and loops, you should be able to figure it out. Beyond that, always remember to try googling things. It may take a few tries to get the right search terms. Ask if you're really stuck.

Comment: I have a for loop,"for letter in decrypt_msg" decrypt_msg being the user entered messege to decrypt, I have tried googling for loops and strings, and also lists. I am trying to figure out how to implement the group of code I previously made into here but I cant figure out how to word it, I really apologize, I wanted to try to figure the rest out myself, but I am just stumped, I appreciate the patience and help you have provided so far.

Comment: Do you know how to turn `"a"` and `"b"` and `"ab"`?

Comment: are you asking how to turn "a" and "b" and then put them together and making them "ab?' cause I do not but atm I have been playing with the code some more and well `def decrypt_letter(decrypt_msg):
    i = 0
    for letter in decrypt_msg:
        i = List1(letter)
        print (i)`
I am getting the error list object is not callable not sure why

Comment: Update I figure out that issues I have it printing the msg but it doesn't print them as one whole word, now I just need to figure out how to combine them and print it as a whole message rather then indivual letters

Comment: 'are you asking how to turn "a" and "b" and then put them together and making them "ab"?' Yes I am. If you don't know how to do that, that shows that you need to spend more time on basic tutorials like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm). The answer is in there. If you can't find it, try and think of words to google to express that operation. If you do `for letter in decrypt_msg` the `letter` is already a string, not an index, so you wouldn't do `List1[letter]`. Printing the letters is not going to help you, you need to store them and the combined result.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I got the program running properly and now all I have to do is attend to any exceptions and such to prevent crashes, thank you for helping me

Answer (score 2):

To 'encrypt', you could do

```
inp = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.1234567890'
oup = '4R5GZ32DAEXYUI6W7OV8FQL0J.H9CBNSPM1TK'
tab = str.maketrans(inp, oup)
totranslate = 'THIS.IS.THE.STRING.TO.TRANSLATE'
totranslate.translate(tab)
```

[`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) builds a table to map the input characters to their corresponding output character.

This table is then used by [`translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to do the actual translation.

Do the reverse to obtain the table for decryption.

Comment: Great, I didn't see that you've given the same answer. `inp= ''.join([str(x) for x in List1])`
`oup= ''.join([str(x) for x in List2])` To convert the list to a string.